# Admin url console not available when running keycloak slave with --backup option

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I am running keycloak in domain master-slave configuration. In order to have dc backup in case master goes down i configured in such a way that am able to connect to connect to domain controller through jboss cli using the command when the master goes down

jboss-cli --connect --controller=localhost
/host-slave:write-local-domain-controller

but am not able to access the admin console

Am not sure why admin console is not available when the slave takes over as master . Can someone throw some light on this

Thanks,
AR